# How to set two boxes as background in Compose without presetting its size

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'd like to create a Composable which is comprised of a 2 tone background and a `Text` box on top if it - see image below. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70698722/compose-place-view-between-two-backgrounds) is very similar, but I don't want to set the size of the Composable - I want it to grow with the size of the text in the middle, and just rely on the padding to show the 2 tones behind it.

[image]

The problem is that when I don't set the size, the composable just takes up all the space possible in the preview, and when displayed on a device, the background completely disappears.

This is my code so far:

```kotlin
    Box(
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(120.dp), // --> I don't want to set this!
    ) {
        Column {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .weight(1f)
                    .background(color = Color.Red),
            )
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .weight(1f)
                    .background(color = Color.Yellow),
            )
        }
        Box {
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(24.dp)
                    .background(color = Color.Cyan),
                text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac est sed dui posuere dictum. Pellentesque vitae gravida justo, vitae fermentum turpis. Fusce diam est, commodo eu volutpat id, dignissim nec ex. ",
            )
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever using `weight` in Column, a parent with fixed height is needed in order to calculate the height of child, if not set it takes the all available space.
To overcome this we can set height of the parent component to `IntrinsicSize.Min`

```
Box(
    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .height(IntrinsicSize.Min)
) { ... }
```

> **Intrinsics lets you query children before they're actually measured.**
>
> To a composable, you can ask for its `intrinsicWidth` or `intrinsicHeight`:
>
> `(min|max)IntrinsicWidth`: Given this height, what's the minimum/maximum width you can paint your content properly?
>
> `(min|max)IntrinsicHeight`: Given this width, what's the minimum/maximum height you can paint your content properly?

Refer to this for more info
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/intrinsic-measurements

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed - setting the outer `Box` height to `IntrinsicSize.Min` achieves the desired look